# AT+HTTPACTION: What is status 606 means?

Tags: arduino-uno

I use Sim808 gprs/gsm/gps module and call these:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+SAPBR=2,1
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPSSL=1
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://www.mywebsite.com/getTime?token=jsdaljdaskl"
AT+HTTPPARA="REDIR",1
AT+HTTPACTION=0
```

I always get `+HTTPACTION: 0,606,0` as the result.

What does 606 mean? I cannot find it everywhere in the documentation.

Comment: The only 606 I can see is an SSL error. Maybe you have an invalid certificate on your site. Try with other sites.

Comment: "606 SSL  alert  message  with  a  level  of  fatal  result  in  
the immediate termination of the connection" https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM800+Series_SSL_Application+Note_V1.00.pdf

Comment: Read here pdf file, exist thi error 606 and error 605 [https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SIM800+Series_SSL_Application+Note_V1.00.pdf][1]